# Why my start page wont't respond to mouse clicks?

Tags: boot, mouse

When I start my PC, some 4 times out of 5, I get stuck at the start page (the one with the password), because it does not respond to mouse clicks. After some reboots from the PC button, the "|" symbol in the password query starts blinking again and I can insert my password.
Smooth sail from there.
If relevant, I run

```
Operating System: Ubuntu Studio 22.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.7
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0
Qt Version: 5.15.3
Kernel Version: 6.5.0-17-lowlatency (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 4 × Intel® Core™ i5-7400 CPU @ 3.00GHz
Memory: 3,7 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 630
```

Comment: Does replugging the mouse help? Does it also occur with touchpads and tablets? A workaround might be to press tab so that you can focus the password box, but it should be already focused

Comment: Neither pressing tab or replugging the mouse help. The "|" line in the password box is showing, but it is not blinking. I can still see the mouse pointer move. No click response though. I have no touchpads and tablets to test.

Comment: It might be that the GPU driver is frozen. The mouse could still be able to move because it's on a separate GPU display plane. If you press CTRL+ALT+F1 and log in at the prompt then run `dmesg`, do you see any errors? Alternatively, do `journalctl -r -b -1` on the next boot

Answer (score 0):

my computer started doing this too, with a wireless mouse. It doesnt respond to any mouse movement. I have to unplug and replug the remote dongle and then it works.